# Sorting objects in EF _context doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, razor

I use Entity Framework. Now I have the following code where I want to sort on Order (custom indexing property, int). When I get the list form _context, change one of the indexes and want to re-sort so that collection is in right order again, it doesn't sort in any way. Tried different ways, and also read different posts. Nothing works...

What am I overseeing?

```
        var oldIdx = oldIndex * 10;
        var newIdx = newIndex * 10;

        // Get ID of changed Note
        var id = _context.Note.Where(x => x.Order == oldIdx).First().ID;

        // Change order of Note
        _context.Note.Where(x => x.Order == oldIdx).First().Order = newIdx - 1;

        // Re-arrange and re-apply order-indexes
        var list = _context.Note.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();   -> this doesn't sort
```

Comment: What is the type of `Order` object?

Comment: `_context.Note` is not a collection, but `IQueryable` representing database table. The `OrderBy` is executed against database table via SQL query. Since you didn't `SaveChanges`, the modified `Order` will not be taken into account.

Comment: You modified `Order` without saving it. You first have to call `SaveChanges` and then do ordering.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks!! Seems that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to get the whole list to another variable and do the processing,

```
        var noteList = _context.Note.ToList();
        // Get ID of changed Note
        var id = noteList.Note.First(x => x.Order == oldIdx).ID;

        // Change order of Note
        noteList.Note.First(x => x.Order == oldIdx).Order = newIdx - 1;

        // Re-arrange and re-apply order-indexes
        var list = noteList.Note.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
```

Comment: Won't it query _all_ elements from database, before it will apply `Where`? Correct me if I'm wrong, but this can kill the application with big database.

Comment: @FCin Yes, it will. `ToList()` executes the query immediately and returns the results. All LINQ functions used on `noteList` afterwards are executed on the in-memory object.

Comment: yes that does. But how ever he needs all the elements I guess, with last line.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `SaveChanges()` job done

You are have to work you whether you want to deal with your data in memory or the DB, not both.

```
// This looks horrible 
//_context.Note.Where(x => x.Order == oldIdx).First().Order = newIdx - 1;

// ahh.. my eyes
var note = _context.Note.Where(x => x.Order == oldIdx).FirstOrDefault();

// sanity check
if(Note == null)
{
    return;
}

note.Order = newIdx - 1;

// save it back to the DB
_context.SaveChanges();

// get your new awesome ordered list
var list = _context.Note.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks... and sorry for your eyes ;-) I'm new in this...

I want to keep the binding to the database, so that I can commit changes with the _context.SaveChanges.